# Does the highlighting library support ASN.1?

Tags: feature-request, formatting

On [one of my answers](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/249512/26186), I provided an illustrative ASN.1 specification to accompany it.

However, I could not find the right language to use to make it ["light up"](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/).

Does StackOverflow or SecuritySE apply any in-house grammars that could be used for this purpose, or is there a grammar ~comparable to ASN.1 in the library somewhere?

Comment: *Creating the new tags `syntax-highlighting` `technical` requires at least 300 reputation.*

Comment: I have added the tag [tag:syntax-highlighting]. (Not sure about the [tag:technical] tag, but others may disagree.)

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to add color or anything fancy on this website, but you can use some basic markup, even in formatted code, by using `<pre>` instead of four leading spaces. Note that you may need to use HTML entities for common symbols (such as using  `&gt;` instead of `>`). Example text showing a simple hello world program in C with the string italicized and all functions made bold:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is done by using the following:

```
<pre>
#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;

int <b>main</b>(void)
{
    <b>printf</b>(<i>"Hello, world!\n"</i>);
    return 0;
}
</pre>
```

I've used this feature a few times, such as in [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/179675/106285) to provide bold, italics, and superscripts:

```
5.2    Parsing the message
The message and its padding must be parsed into N m-bit blocks.

5.2.1  SHA-1, SHA-224 and SHA-256
For SHA-1, SHA-224 and SHA-256, the message and its padding are parsed into N
512-bit blocks, M(1), M(2),..., M(N). Since the 512 bits of the input block may be
expressed as sixteen 32-bit words, the first 32 bits of message block i are
denoted M0(i), the next 32 bits are M1(i), and so on up to M15(i).

5.2.2  SHA-334, SHA-512, SHA-512/224 and SHA-512/256
For SHA-384, SHA-512, SHA-512/224 and SHA-512/256, the message and its padding are
parsed into N1024-bit blocks, M(1), M(2),..., M(N). Since the 1024 bits of the input
block may be expressed as sixteen 64-bit words, the first 64 bits of message block
i are denoted M0(i), the next 64 bits are M1(i), and so on up to M15(i).
```

Comment: Hah, that's a pretty zany and creative solution! It might even be helpful for highlighting particular portions of some code.